# achartEngine: Values change while panning chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an aChartEngine chart with values displayed on chart. Problem is that when I pan chart horizontally or vertically, values change. Look at these two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

```
private GraphicalView initGraph(String chartTitle, String xTitle, String yTitle, String[] titles, List<double[]> x, List<double[]> values, int[] colors, PointStyle[] styles) {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setTextTypeface(getDefaultTypeface());
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 60, 50, 10 }); // TOP,LEFT,BOTTOM,RIGHT

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

    int length = colors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors[i]);
        r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        r.setChartValuesFormat(format);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }

    renderer.setChartTitle(chartTitle);
    renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
    renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    //renderer.setXLabels(10);
    //renderer.setYLabels(5);
    //renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelFormat(format);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    int titlesLength = titles.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < titlesLength; i++) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], 0);
        double[] xV = x.get(i);
        double[] yV = values.get(i);
        int seriesLength = xV.length;
        for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
            series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }

    return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, renderer);
}
```

Comment: What version of ACE are you using?

Comment: achartengine-1.1.0.jar

Comment: Please try with the version here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/